# Storing keys in a redis set

Tags: redis

I'm just starting to use redis and I want to retrieve a part of the key-value pairs (like a `SELECT` or `find`).
My plan is to save the relevant keys in a set. So I will use `SMEMBERS`, get the keys and then use `MGET` for each element.

Is it the proper way to achieve my goal or there's a better built-in mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the basic approach to "indexing" in Redis. If your set is large, you'd want to use `SSCAN` instead of `SMEMBERS`. Also, don't use a single `MGET` for everything, but rather make batches of constant size (e.g. 100). These two methods will allow better concurrency.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thanks that's all I needed to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, that's the basic approach to "indexing" in Redis. If your set is
>   large, you'd want to use SSCAN instead of SMEMBERS. Also, don't use a
>   single MGET for everything, but rather make batches of constant size
>   (e.g. 100). These two methods will allow better concurrency.

– Itamar Haber